# compiler rules for recognizing always evaluated branches of if

Tags: typescript

In this code:

```
class Abc {
    field1: string;

    constructor(data: string) {
        if (true) {
            this.field1 = "";
        }
    }

}
```

there is no compiler error.

But if I change the expression in `if` condition to `data !== null`, then there is compiler error of: `Property 'field1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor`. But from the point of view of compiler, datatype of `string` should never be null, that can only be `string | null`. Why is compiler giving this error?

Comment: `new Abc(null as any)`. Also, don't forget about `never`. It is assignable to any type. See example:  `tsplay.dev/WJ86ZN`